# Write datas from Stripe API in a CSV file in golang

Tags: api, csv, go, stripe-payments

I am trying to retrieve Stripe datas and parse them into a CSV file.
Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go"
    "github.com/stripe/stripe-go/invoice"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "encoding/csv"
)

func main() {
    stripe.Key = "" // I can't share the API key
    params := &stripe.InvoiceListParams{}
    params.Filters.AddFilter("limit", "", "3")
    params.Filters.AddFilter("status", "", "paid")
    i := invoice.List(params)

    // Create a CSV file
    csvdatafile, err := os.Create("./mycsvfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer csvdatafile.Close()
    // Write Unmarshaled json data to CSV file
    w := csv.NewWriter(csvdatafile)
    //Column title
    var header []string
    header = append(header, "ID")
    w.Write(header)
    for i.Next() {
        in := i.Invoice()
        fmt.Printf(in.ID) // It is working
        w.Write(in) // It is not working
    }
    w.Flush()
    fmt.Println("Appending succed")
}
```

When I am running my program with `go run *.go` I obtain the following error:

```
./main.go:35:10: cannot use in (type *stripe.Invoice) as type []string in argument to w.Write
```

I think I am not far from the solution.
I just need to understand how to write correctly in the CSV file thank's to `w.Write()` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the doc, the Write function is:

```
func (w *Writer) Write(record []string) error
```

That is, it is expecting you to pass a slice of strings representing a line of CSV data with each string being a slice. So, if you have only one field, you have to pass a string slice of 1:

```
 w.Write([]string{in.ID})
```

Comment: I have the following error now 
./main.go:35:20: cannot use in (type *stripe.Invoice) as type string in array or slice literal

Comment: try this:  w.Write([]string{in.ID})